# Can auto mappings conventions work with mapping overrides?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a convention for my ids, which automatically maps properties with a name of `Id` as the identifier. As requirements are being fleshed out I need to tweak a domain model so naturally I went online and found that I need to create a class that inherits from `IAutoMappingOverride<T>`.

My convention:

```
public class PrimaryKeyConvention : IIdConvention, IIdConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column("Id");
        instance.GeneratedBy.SeqHiLo(instance.Name, "10");
    }

    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IIdentityInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Generator, Is.Not.Set);
    }
}
```

My override:

```
public class LocateMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Locate>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Locate> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(x => x.SendTo).Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

The convention does work as expected if I remove my override.

The exception I get is `The entity 'LocateMappingOverride' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id).`.

Is it possible to use conventions in conjunction with mapping overrides?

Comment: Might want to consider Nhibernate 3.2 built in mappings by code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is - yes, automapping can work with overrides.

Look what the error said. The problem is not with `Locate` entity, but with `LocateMappingOverride` entity, and that class should not be treated as entity, of course. You must have `IAutomappingConfiguration` configured so that FluentNHibernate's rule what to treat as entity includes `LocateMappingOverride`, too. And it does not have an Id mapped, indeed.

You should either:

- change your `IAutomappingConfiguration` so that classes that implements `IAutoMappingOverride<>` are excluded
- move the override outside the scope that is searched for entities
- or introduce a common marker interface that all entities need to implement, i.e. `IEntity` and change `IAutomappingConfiguration` rules respectively.

Comment: Woah. You are absolutely right. I totally overlooked that. Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 for same problem - I added a where clause when automapping my domain assembly as follows:
`.Where(t => !t.GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.IsGenericType).Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IAutoMappingOverride<>)))
`